# Unable to configure Notepad++ DBGP plugin. Xdebug already installed

Tags: php, notepad++, xdebug, dbg

I have installed `xdebug` on `PHP` but now I can't make the `notepad++` `DBGp` plugin work.

I have latest `wamp` version on `Win7` and the `wwww` folder is on partition: `d:\www`.

I have coded a test file `test.php` :

```
<?php
    $test = "3";
    echo $test;
?>
```

And I have tried opening it in web browser using this link :

```
http://localhost/test.php?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=test
```

But the `DBGp` won't connect. I tried with and without `IDE_Key`.

I have gone through the documentation many times but was unable to find/solve the issue. Hopefully someone could know the reason.

Below are some screenshots:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you set any breakpoints in Notepad++? If not then you should check the "Break at first line when debugging starts" checkbox.

Comment: I tried as you said...I tried with breakpoints as well, but still won't move. I expect the dropdown "disconnected" should change or the notepad++ should flash on the taskbar.

Comment: @FarcasO. did you ever find a solution for this? I'm experiencing the same.

Comment: Solved, changing the ports on both the xdebug settings and the dbgp settings did it for me.

Comment: You should write the solution as an answer and accept it.

Comment: If you are debugging with Notepad++ you might want to reconsider your approach. Maybe use an IDE like Netbeans instead?  I found setting up xdebug relatively painless with the latest version ( 8+) . –  Joelerr 15 mins ago

Answer (score 1):

To fix this issue, the ports on both the xdebug settings and the dbgp settings needed to be changed.

It is unclear from the above comments whether it was because they both attempted to use the same port, ports were used by other applications etc. but perhaps Kandinski can clarify this by editing this answer when they see it.

*(Posting the given answer [see comments on question] to remove the question from the unanswered queue. User was asked over 3 years ago to do this but has not done so yet. Credit for this answer remains theirs)*

Answer (score 0):

You have to set xdebug to automatically accept new debug connections:

```
 $ cat /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/xdebug.ini
  zend_extension=/usr/lib/php5/20121212/xdebug.so
  xdebug.remote_enable=1
  xdebug.remote_autostart=1
  xdebug.remote_host="127.0.0.1"
  xdebug.remote_port=9000
  xdebug.idekey="CLUJ3$"
```

Obviously if you are running PHP as FPM you have to change the default port to 9000 to some other ( Ex: 9001 )

Restart apache after.

Answer (score 0):

Install Chrome XDebug Helper. In options, set IDE Key = Others and value = default.
Works for me.

```
    [Xdebug]
    zend_extension="php_xdebug.dll"
    xdebug.remote_enable=1
    xdebug.remote_port=9000
    xdebug.autostart=on 
    xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
    xdebug.remote_mode=req
    xdebug.idekey=default
```