# How to have Notepad++ read dbgp plugin?

Tags: notepad++, xdebug

I'm totally noob about this.

So, I've just downloaded WAMP Server version 2.5.
There are two php.ini files in the installation folder,
and using Notepad version 7.6.6 (32 bit) I change the "off" to "on" 
to both php.ini files, as seen below:

1. C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.9\bin
   [image]
2. C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12
   [image]

There is already a file *php_xdebug-2.2.5-5.5-vc11.dll* in:
C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12\zend_ext

I also download DBGpPlugin_0_13b_dll.zip, extract it, then put the dll file in :
C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\plugins\dbgpPlugin\dbgpPlugin.dll

So I start the WampServer, it show green icon in the taskbar,
and the php info is like this :
[image]
[image]

Then I open the Notepad++ ---> Plugin ---> DBGp ---> Configure.
But I get a blank DBGp configuration window:
[image]

while from the internet, it say the Remote Server IP columns should read : 127.0.0.1

What did I do wrong ?
Is there another step which I have to do ?

BTW, I've read a similar question in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7791010/unable-to-configure-notepad-dbgp-plugin-xdebug-already-installed),
but there is no acceptable answer there.

Comment: Tried clicking the add button?

Comment: @Derick, thanks for your advice. Following your instruction, I put 127.0.01 (IP) and xdebug (IDE), Path, etc, then click ADD button. Still no work. Now I want to try to restart the computer :).